# what is the difference between importing python sub-modules from NumPy, matplotlib packages

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, matplotlib

When I try to use `pyplot` from `matplotlib`:

```
import matplotlib
print matplotlib.pyplot  # just checking
```

It gives me `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'pyplot'`

It can be solved with:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot
```

But what I am really confused with is,

```
import numpy
print numpy.random
```

gives me `<module 'numpy.random' from '/Applications/Canopy.app/appdata/canopy-1.0.3.1262.macosx-x86_64/Canopy.app/Contents/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/random/__init__.pyc'>`

What is the difference between two cases? `pyplot` cannot be called in the first example, but `random` was in the second. I think it's related with some kind of packages and modules. But I'm not such a professional to the python, thus asking for an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the definitive tutorial, [read this](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html).

But for your specific case, it looks like this is what's happening:

Every directory-based python module (like `matplotlib` and `numpy`) has an `__init__.py` file, which determines what is brought into the module's top-level scope. By default (when `__init__.py` is empty), nothing is in scope.

However, some modules (like `numpy`) have decided to hoist functionality into the top-level by adding import statements to `__init__.py`. This brings those submodules into scope, even if you've only explicitly imported `numpy`.

To check our assumptions, let's look at the source!

- [matplotlib's `__init__.py`](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/lib/matplotlib/__init__.py) doesn't include the statement `import pyplot`.
- [numpy's `__init__.py`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/__init__.py#L176) does include `import random`, on line 176.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that in the `__init__.py` of a module, it can use a variable `__all__` to control what variables or functions to be imported in the current scope when you write a statement looks like: `from modulename import *` ; I thinks it also works for the syntax `import modulename`;In the `__init__.py` file of numpy, I find the following code:

```
__all__.extend(['linalg', 'fft', 'random', 'ctypeslib', 'ma'])
```

Comment: The `__all__` variable only affects star-imports: http://stackoverflow.com/a/64130/10601

Comment: Thank you very much, I think I understand the difference now